# How many regions at the most can 5 identical rectangles divide the plane into?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

A rectangle divides a plane into 2 regions at the most. How many regions at the most can 5 identical rectangles divide the plane into?

I think the answer is $2^5=32$, but the answer provided in the book is $82$. Could you please help me out? Many thanks.

Comment: How did you arrive at $2^5$?

Comment: by induction, with one more rectangle, we can at most double the number of the regions. Hence $2^5$ (in general $2^n$).

Comment: @maomao With only two rectangles, you can get $6$ regions if you arrange them in an X shape.

Comment: Aha, I see, did not think carefully. ;-)

Comment: If the question were about (infinite) lines, then your reasoning would be correct. :)

Comment: is there a general formula for arbitrary $n$. Just for $n=2$, is 6 the maximum?

Comment: @maomao: For $n=2$ you can get $10$: arrange them using the same scheme that David G. Stork used in his answer. That scheme will in general produce $4n(n-1)+2$ regions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Many thanks for your kind answer.

Comment: @maomao: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows that $32$ is certainly low:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I realized my mistake. A general formula for $n$?

Comment: You're fairly new here, so I won't lash out... but I will say it is *very* bad form, and disrespectful to helpers, to *change* your question (you said nothing whatsoever about general $n$), especially after an answer has been provided.

Comment: sorry, your answer is right and I am very grateful, but I do not think asking an extra question is disrespectful.

Comment: It *is* disrespectful because a person who knows the answer to the second question passes by, and those who answer question 1 are frustrated in thinking they did not finish the "real" question that was asked.